# Getting 2 different lengths for a text field in perl from a DBI query

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have encrypted data in a mysql table stored as a text field.
Everything was originally written in Windows perl and that still works without issue.
My problem is that I am running the same code on Linux and when I query the table the text result in perl tells me it is longer (which causes my decryption to blow up since it is too long).

This happens running the same script so I know there is not a code difference.
Mysql server is 5.1.63 running on OpenSuSE Linux 11.4 x64.
Linux perl is v5.12.3
Windows perl is 5.10.1
The field in question is defined as text, utf8_general_ci and when I access it via JDBC the data reports 128 bytes, 
the SQL in question is simple (pruned down to just what matters here)

```
my $gatherSQL = "select 
                  table.encryptedText from action.theTable table
                  where table.custno=" . $dbHandle->quote($custno) 
  my $getHandle = $dbHandle->prepare($gatherSQL);
  $getHandle->execute();
  my $arrayRef = $getHandle->fetchall_arrayref();
  foreach my $myrow (@$arrayRef)
  {
    $type = $$myrow[0];
  }
  $getHandle->finish();
#DB Handle is opened with a simple  
my $workSQLhandle = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$dataDB:$dataServer:$dataPort", $userToUse, $pwToUse);
return($workSQLhandle);
```

When I run the code in Windows (through a samba share) I get a length of the field of 128 (which decrypts)
Same code on the same machine run from a command prompt tells me the same return string is 193 chars long (and won't decrypt)
I did a compare of the results coming back and they are identical but perl tells me one is longer than the other.

Any thoughts on how I can address this and what the root cause is?

Comment: check if perhaps mysql/perl are doing some translations on the text. e.g `select length(table.encryptedText)` to see what mysql thinks the length is. encrypted text tends to look like binary garbage, and if you're storing it in a `TEXT`-type field, it *WILL* be subject to automatic charset translation. encrypted data should go into BLOB fields, which are otherwise identical to TEXT, but are *NOT* charset-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I will check into that and see what I find (I am hesitant to make structural changes to the DB since most of the processes in place work as intended right now, perhaps I will add another field to the table and update from 1 to the other....

Comment: Marc, can you submit as an answer so I can accept?
You were right on the money (now I just need to fix the DB and update the stored procedure which writes to the field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if perhaps mysql/perl are doing some translations on the text. e.g `select length(table.encryptedText)` to see what mysql thinks the length is. encrypted text tends to look like binary garbage, and if you're storing it in a TEXT-type field, it WILL be subject to automatic charset translation. encrypted data should go into BLOB fields, which are otherwise identical to TEXT, but are NOT charset-sensitive.